# Is it possible to limit the resolution of images in the PhotoEditorSDK iOS SDK?

Tags: photoeditorsdk

Is it possible to set a max size on the images captured in the `CameraViewController` and edited in `PhotoEditViewController`?

As an example I'd like to limit images to a `maxWidth` of `1600` and `maxHeight` of `1600` so if a user takes a `3024×4032` photo I'd like PESDK to provide back a `1200x1600` image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed resolution is currently not supported but it is being worked on. You can however set a fixed aspect ratio by first setting `PhotoEditViewControllerOptions.forceCropMode` to `true` ([described here](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/apidocs/ios/v8_2/Classes/PhotoEditViewControllerOptions.html#/c:@M@PhotoEditorSDK@objc(cs)PESDKPhotoEditViewControllerOptions(py)forceCropMode)), setting `TransformToolControllerOptions.allowFreeCrop` to `false` ([described here](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/apidocs/ios/v8_2/Classes/TransformToolControllerOptions.html#/c:@M@PhotoEditorSDK@objc(cs)PESDKTransformToolControllerOptions(py)allowFreeCrop)) and then setting `TransformToolControllerOptions.allowedCropAspects` ([described here](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/apidocs/ios/v8_2/Classes/TransformToolControllerOptions.html#/c:@M@PhotoEditorSDK@objc(cs)PESDKTransformToolControllerOptions(py)allowedCropAspects)) to the crop aspect ratios that your image must have (e.g. 1:1).

Comment: Thanks @Sascha. FWIW, I'm not looking for a "fixed resolution" but rather a "maximum size". So in my example if a user takes a 3024×4032 photo I'd like PESDK to provide me a 1200x1600 image. So maintain the original aspect ratio but scale it to ensure it has a width <= 1600 and height <= 1600. I'm currently doing this in CoreGraphics but seems like it would be useful feature of the API. I updated my question to clarify.